# Starting android emulator and running tests

Tags: android, bash, testing, adb

I'm writing a script that performs a series of operations on an Android emulator.  I'd like to start the emulator, and run of suite of tests.  So far I have:

```
(emulator-ARM @emuName) & adb wait-for-device; adb shell am instrument -w com.name.name.android.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

But All this does is kicks off the emulator, and returns an error that reads:

```
android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
```

It seems to me that wait-for-device is simply waiting for a device to be connected, not for a device to be ready, which is what I think I need

Anyone else had this problem, or has a suggestion?

Comment: What IDE are you using to write your tests?

Comment: Restart ADB, list devices: `adb devices`

Comment: @BlaineAnderson, the tests were written in eclipse.

Comment: @pawelzieba running adb devices lists me the emulator device.

Comment: Are these JUnit tests? What testing platform are you using?

Comment: Yeah, the suite is made up of Android JUnit tests.  I want to run them from the command line, which I can do, but I need to start the emulator for them to run.

Comment: Why not use [android-maven-plugin](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/plugin-info.html) whcih has all these functions built in.

Comment: I'm more curious as to why this doesn't work.  I've gotten around it by polling the device with 'adb shell ls' and waiting until that runs successfully (as that means the device has finished booting).

Comment: Has this ever been solved, or have you found a workaround for Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [Android Debug Bridge / Commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary) / Scripting / wait-for-device, it is exactly as you said (*It seems to me that wait-for-device is simply waiting for a device to be connected, not for a device to be ready...*). Unfortunately, there is no command mentioned which does what you need.